# Binding scope variable(array) to drop down on focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a MEAN stack application where I have table with two columns and many(100's) of row. One of the column in each row contains drop down defined as `inputDropdown` below:

```
.directive('inputDropdown', function($compile) {

    var template = 
        '<input class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled">' +
        '<div class="dropdown">' + 
            '<div class="form-control" ng-repeat="value in list | filter:ngModel">' +
                '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            list: '=',
            onSelect: '&',
            disabled:'=ngDisabled'
        },
        template: template,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs,mapController) {
            element.addClass('input-dropdown');

            if(scope.$parent.setDirty)
            {
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            }
            scope.select = function(e, value) {
                scope.ngModel = value;
                // scope.onSelect({$event: e, value: value});
                scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
            };
        }
    };
})
```

and HTML:

```
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="var in Mappings | filter: searchVariable">
        <td>{{var.Name}}</td>
        <td>
          <div><input-dropdown name="fqn" ng-model="var.Variable" list="variables" ng-disabled="(var.IsDisable)"></input-dropdown></div> 
        </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

In directive, the list(`variables` in HTML) used in `ng-repeat` contains 70K entries, so it freezes the entire UI because it binds for every row as the list is same for every row.

What I want to achieve is whenever user click on the dropdown div then only the scope variable/list should be rendered for that particular row and on blur it should remove that.

Or suggest me a way to lazy loading from the scope variable(list) and display in the dropdown.

Comment: Sorry, what should happen when you click on the drop-down?

Comment: @AlexisToby It will show all the values in list as options. I want to implement dynamic binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply asking for the     [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) and [ng-focus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) directives?

```
.directive('inputDropdown', function($compile) {

var template = 
    '<input class="form-control" ng-model="ngModel" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-focus="setDirectiveList()" ng-blur="removeDirectiveList()">' +
    '<div class="dropdown" ng-click="setDirectiveList()">' + 
        '<div class="form-control" ng-repeat="value in selectedList | filter:ngModel">' +
            '<div ng-mousedown="select($event, value)">{{value}}</div>' + 
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '^form',
    scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        list: '=',
        onSelect: '&',
        disabled:'=ngDisabled'
    },
    template: template,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs,mapController) {
        element.addClass('input-dropdown');

        if(scope.$parent.setDirty)
        {
            scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
        }
        scope.select = function(e, value) {
            scope.ngModel = value;
            // scope.onSelect({$event: e, value: value});
            scope.makeFormDirty = mapController.$setDirty();
        };
        scope.setDirectiveList= function() {
            scope.selectedList = list;
        }
        scope.removeDirectiveList= function() {
            scope.selectedList = [];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do i need to change/add(ng-focus & ng-blur)  in my view part(html)? Because this is not working.

Comment: yes you would add the two directives to the template of your directive, so that it can invoke the two new functions on the scope of your directive. I modified the template in my post, so you can see I used (ng-click) on the dropdown div, and  (ng-blur) and (ng-focus) on the input. Also a 70k item dropdown seems like bad UX for me, I would suggest another component. Perhaps something like an autosuggest box instead